# How to set a value dynamically for dropdownlist in code behind C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I need to set value "Y" to dropdownlist control dynamically.When i tried by selectedValue it gave error like object reference is null .plz help

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that Y is there inside your `asp:DropDownList`. Then do this

```
if (DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("Y") != null)
{
     DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("Y").Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "Y" is in  your dropdownlist:

DropDownList1.SelectedValue=DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("Y").Tostring();

It works.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedValue`  will only work when using data binding.  If you filled out the list manually via the Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio or by manipulating the `DropDownList.Items` collection, you need to use `SelectedItem` as below:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem = "Y";
```